# Label of plotting elements of matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix, graphics3d, legending

I have a little quest.
I have a matrix which elements are functions of two variables:

```
matrix[x_,y_]={{Sin[x y],Cos[x+y]},{Sin[x],Cos[y]}}
```

Then I want a 3-dimensionally plot and I used:

```
Plot3D[matrix[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

I obtained:

[image]

I tried to use the specified command to create labels or legend, but it didn't work.
Is there a way to color and label every single elements like independent function of the two variables?

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
matrix[x_, y_] = {{Sin[x y], Cos[x + y]}, {Sin[x], Cos[y]}};

Plot3D[matrix[x, y] // Flatten // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly!